# Gnome Shell Extension Override C API?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

This may be a question where the answer can be a url to a descent gnome shell extension tutorial because I'm not finding one.

**The Problem I have, which I want to solve with a Gnome Extension**

In the gnome settings daemon (see https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/plugins/power/gsd-backlight-helper.c#n123 ), I would like to override the following function

```
clamp_minimum (gint max, gint value)
{
    gint minimum;
    /* If the interface has less than 100 possible values, it's
     * likely that 0 doesn't turn the backlight off so we let 0 be
     * set in that case. */
    if (max > 99)
        minimum = 1;
    else
        minimum = 0;

    return MAX (value, minimum);
}
```

I would like this method to always return 0 since that way the lowest setting for screen brightness would become 0 i.e. pitch black which would finally let me operate the computer at night when listening to music without turning on the screen all the time.

Basically, XFCE, MacOS, Cinnamon and others already have this implemented, but Gnome for some reason went this way.

So, my question is: can I override or intercept the call to this function to always return 0 from a Gnome extension?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a complete separate binary... gnome-shell can't modify it in any way

Comment: So my best bet is to build this binary myself after having changed the code in the above method?

Comment: Assuming the helper binary is what is used to change the brightness,  I guess that would work

Comment: Did you find any solution for that ? I would like to change the minimum level ( the actual one is too low to be useful )  ...

Comment: I submitted this bug report: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780554

Comment: @WonderLand I switched to XFCE

Answer (score 0):

To answer your explicit question: no, you cannot override or intercept a call to this function.

You could, however, write a shell extension that allows you to toggle the screen to a permanent off status when the system isn't locked/logged off (as logging off calls disable() on all extensions and sets the GNOME Shell mode to gdm).